# Upgraded HP Laptop to Windows 7- Printer won't work

Tags: printer

My HP Laptop was upgraded to Windows 7 from Vista a few months ago. My newer Epson printer works fine in Thailand but the older HP Photosmart printer (at my USA home) won't work. The computer recognizes the Photosmart as a storage device, not a printer. Any ideas how to fix ?

Comment: Have you tried checking HP.com for Windows 7 drivers for your specific HP model?

Answer (score 1):

Oftentimes, you have to reinstall the driver when you upgrade Windows. The printer should work fine if you check [HP.com](http://hp.com) or [epson.com](http://epson.com) and search their support pages for drivers to find the one that matches your model, then install that.

Comment: I tried that...HP says that driver is not available for download and must be obtained thru Windows Update via USB. This doesn't work either.